# Story identification: all communications down

Tags: story-identification

I remembered a scene from a film or TV episode earlier today, where people are remarking that all communications are down, up to and including [string telephones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tin_can_telephone). I believe that the medium was in some sort of sci-fi, but I don't recall.

Any leads ?

Comment: escape from LA?  any more details you can remember?

Comment: @mgh42 never seen *Escape from LA*

Comment: How can "string telephones" be down? It's just a piece of string with two cups. Do you mean "landline phones"?

Comment: @DavidTonhofer, probably for the purpose of hyperbole addressing how every means of communication is down

Comment: Does the line "... they got Ma Bell!" sound familiar? That's from the original made for TV movie "V" from the... errr... early 1980's?

Comment: @S.Manke, No. I also don't believe that I ever saw *V*. I believe that this was more recent and almost definitely higher-budget (but am uncertain)

Answer (score 1):

Could this be the Ray Bradbury short story from 1957 titled "Almost the End of the World"

It can be read online here

http://raybradbury.ru/library/story/57/10/0/

Comment: I'd suspect not, if even tin-can 'telephones' don't work; that story uses sunspots as the disabling mechanism, and TCTs wouldn't be affected by sunspots.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin Probably the reference to TCT (cited in the question) is hyperbole, not to be taken literally.